# reduce my 90gb collection of mp3 to about 10gb

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, mp3, opus

got an insanely simple and working script already:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

mkdir .before
mkdir .error
for i in *.m??; do
        ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -b:a 16k "${i%.*}.opus" && mv "$i" .before/
        mv "$i" .error/
done

echo zzz finished $TITLE | termux-notification
termux-vibrate -f
```

of course the important command is just `ffmpeg` there, but just keep in mind my context, please. termux. android only. simplicity... and immensely reducing my music collection size!

everything works fine with this...

except for my minor issue of the week:

## the album art is lost!

there are many questions in sen dealing with this, and [different reasons why (apparently all related to how ogg and opus containers work)](https://dogphilosophy.net/?p=54) it's actually way more complicated than it may appear at first sight.

the only proclaimed solution i could find so far is a script from 2014 which doesn't handle opus:

https://superuser.com/a/706808/28411

can you help me keeping this simple?

or else, i will just output it to a image file of same name and deal with it another year.

edit: [How can I copy coverart from flac to opus with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1209424/how-can-i-copy-coverart-from-flac-to-opus-with-ffmpeg) doesn't really answer the question. it solves the album, but i can't find a configuration with `opusenc` which keeps the file at 10%. setting the same bitrate (16k) gets it to 20% at best.

Comment: FFmpeg currently does not support muxing album/cover art in Opus. See [#4448 Properly support cover art in ogg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4448) and [#9044 Writing album art to ogg / opus files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9044). You will have to use another tool, such as `opusenc`, to add the album art.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, @ilogan, but so far it brought me more issues than do solutions! please, see the edit.

Comment: I reopened but the question seems like multiple questions in one: 1) *How to add cover art to Opus file?* 2) *How to make my Opus file to be 10% or smaller than input size?* Multi-questions tend not to get answered.

Comment: @llogan please see the solution. sorry for my dumbness, and thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i'm using effectively now:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# use this for big folders
# mkdir .before; mkdir .error

for i in *.m??; do
        # main activity: compress mp3 down to 10%, with reduced album art!
        ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i "$i" -c:v mjpeg -vsync 2 -vf scale=320:-1 -f flac - | opusenc - --bitrate 16 --music --framesize 40 "${i%.*}.opus" && mv "$i" .before/

        # some times opusenc don't work
        ffmpeg -hide_banner -n -i "$i" -b:a 16k -c:v mjpeg -vs
ync 2 -vf scale=320:-1 "${i%.*}.opus" && mv "$i" .before/

        # error catcher, if the folder exists
        mv "$i" .error/
done

# notify when finished, d'uh
echo zzz finished $TITLE | termux-notification
termux-vibrate -f
```

in the end, the problem with `opusenc` was actually the art size being too big! it even encodes a bit better than ffmpeg, when it works (very rarely it can't read the input. ffmpeg never failed, though).